# How to get data from modal window?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, modal-dialog

I've a modal dialog.

```
<div id="myLoginModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Войти в учетную запись</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="login">Логин</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input id="login" name="login" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="password">Пароль</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control input-md" required="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="loginBttn" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Войти</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Отмена</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

...and have menu.php file.

```
<?php
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
echo $login.$password;
```

How can I get and load in div element user's login and password from modal dialog when he is pressing submit button?

I've tried to write that, but it's not working - exception "undefined index $login and $password".

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#loginBttn").click(function() {
        $("#content").load('menu.php');
    });
});
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Use ajax form submit, and success callback to change your html content.

Comment: buttons are outside the form, for one thing

Comment: Fred, it's a typical form using bootstrap styles.

Comment: abeayaz, please, send code examples, I can not find anything!(

Comment: I wrote an answer with example

Answer (score 0):

You can submit the form and use the success callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#loginBttn").click(function() {
        $.post('menu.php', $("#myLoginModal form").serialize(), function(html){
     $('#content').html(html);
}, 'html')
   });
});
```

EDIT: Also you can check https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: This code loads the .php file even before the set on the button "submit"

Comment: Ofc. You should add it to click event. I edited the answer for you

Comment: Thanks for the advice, everything works fine by clicking on the button. 
But there is a small problem, in the end the result is waiting for me:
"Notice: Undefined index: login in menu.php on line 2
Notice: Undefined index: password in menu.php on line 3".

Comment: If you enter sth in the inputs it cant give this error. Do you also get what you typed or just this notice ?

Comment: my inputs aren't clear and I see only that errir message.

Comment: can you try `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_POST`  ?

Comment: after all it's not working. i've just added screenshots about result. check please.

Comment: You should check the chrome network console to see whats going with the post method. The parameters are not posted appearently

Comment: if i'm using "if(isset($_POST['login'], $_POST['password'])) {
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    echo $login.$password;
}" - result is empty.

Comment: mb it's php 7.1 has problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

I've just used PHP Tools for VS and I did it!
The problem was the default settings for the php interpreter v7.1 !